# Using tamper data from within my plugin

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, xul, browser-addons, tamper-data

I'm trying to develop an extension to modify certain script loads on the fly in Firefox (eg. building a JSON params file having a fixed file name, intercepting it's original load and injecting the custom file in). Is there any way to utilize the functionality of Tamper data or similar plugins for the intercept and replace part? Or could someone please point to a resource which could help me do the intercepting by myself?

Please pardon me if this was obvious, I'm starting out with plugin development for Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself, went with a separate ASP.net project to perform these functions and redirected to generated files using Fiddlercore packages